# MySQL to automatically import a Web Query IQY

Tags: mysql, sql, database

We have a cloud base accounting software, NETSUITE.

I have set up a report which provides me with the necessary information for our current stock.

This information can be accessed by a web query .iqy file from any location in the world.

I would like a separate MYSQL database which is hosted to import this data into a table I have set up.

This is needed as NETSUITE will not allow me to run certain commands that I require.

Is this possible and how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL can import CSV data, google `mysql load data infile`.

Another option is to use phpMyAdmin and select one of the import options in that tool.
There are also commercial tools available like DBForge for MySQL that will allow importing tables into mySQL.

Comment: Thank you Johan, I should of provided slightly more information. I use phpMyAdmin to manage the MySQL. I have tried to use the .iqy file and select excel 97-2003 as the format of the imported .iqy file. However this does not seem to work. I get error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET) The connection was reset.